# Postgresql config parameters not reflecting even after service restart

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I changed

```
  client_min_messages =  warning
```

in postgresql.conf file.

I have restarted service after this change. 
But when I fetch data using command

```
`select * from pg_settings where name  = 'client_min_messages'`
```

in pg_admin, it still shows **notice** instead of **warning**.

below is the output of the query

[image]

I again changed value to log and restarted service and below is the output of the same

[image]

Comment: Maybe you edited the wrong file? You can verify that using `show config_file;` Or the config file includes a second file that overwrites your setting. You can verify that using: `select setting, sourcefile, sourceline from pg_settings where name = 'client_min_messages'`

Comment: I edited correct file. I am getting changed value at local. i changed value to error and it reflected at local but not on remote server. even, reset_val parameter reflecting changes but setting is unchanged.

Comment: Also, check the source of the value you observe in `pg_settings`.

Comment: If you changed the setting in your local `postgresql.conf` then why do you expect the **remote** server to change?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :  i was connecting that server from remote.   when i connect from local, it reflect changes

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe :  source is session. but when i open new query window in pg_admin, it still shows source as session and value  is not updated.

Comment: You should edit the question and describe *exactly* what you did. The way the question currently is, it is unclear.

Comment: `source = 'session'` seems to indicate that pgAdmin changes this value when you connect. What do you see if you use `psql` instead?

Comment: Also (unrelated): you don't need to restart the service after that change. A simple `select pg_reload_conf()` to reload the configuration file would have been enough.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :  i see correct value using psql.

Comment: I think its the functionality of pgadmin, that's why we are able to see useful messages in pgadmin.